# How to use custom directive with ng-template and ngIf?

Tags: angular

I need to generate a component dynamically. I followed [this tutorial](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader) of Dynamic Component Loader. The problem is that I use `*ngIf` directive in my template. Now I'm stuck at the following error in my `AdBannerComponent`:

```
TypeError: "this.adHost is undefined"
```

The code from the tutorial is provided on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vj4ky4).

Here is the code of my `AdBannerComponent` template:

```
<div *ngIf="flag">
    <h3>Advertisements {{flag.name}}:</h3>
    <ng-template ad-host></ng-template>
</div>
```

How should I use `ng-template` to display generated component with `ngIf` directive?

Comment: Couldn't find `*ngIf` anywhere in your Template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of you have used view child. If you want to use **viewchild** the component should be rendered as a child component. but with *ngIf it is conditionally rendered. so you can use **display:none** style instead of ***ngIf**. *display:none* only change the *visibility*.

please refer this [link](https://www.angularjswiki.com/angular/difference-between-ngif-and-hidden-or-displaynone-in-angular/) for understand about ***ngIf** vs **display:none**

Your edited [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nkvnpa?file=src/app/ad-banner.component.ts)

Comment: Ok, but what if I want to use `ngIf`? How to render the component?

Comment: You cant with viewchild. Viewchild is a refrence of the rendered component.if there is no component it is throwing error.*ngIf doing conditionally rendering.that link which I put shows the differences.

Comment: The `flag` value will be received from my API, so with `ngIf` I could avoid error `flag is undefined`.

Comment: If `display: none` is the only way... yes.

Comment: No this is not the only way but this a one way. you can check conditionally viewchild and do the rest stuff.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184149/discussion-between-asanka-and-fil).